# How to auto generate a page from inputs through form on website

Tags: web-applications

Lets suppose i am having a website www.examplesite.com on which I post a form.

When user fills the desired fields and click on submit button then a page must be generated which looks like a pdf document or document typed in Ms_Word.

Secondly, the page which generates would be a custom designed page which I would be designing, it should also contain the text which user dosnt enter but i had given it while designing. In short if I can say a page which contains dynamic value input by user in front of static values which I had designed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to have a template of some description. If you mean looks like a PDF or word document then you just want it to look professional, or do you actually want a PDF or word document?

You've not mentioned which technologies you have to work with, or what you're familiar with. I see two solutions:

If you are already familiar with server side scripting (Perl, PHP, ASP..) then each of these languages has a method for creating PDFs from templates, populated with data.

Without using server side scripting you could use [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) and populate an HTML template with values from the form input.